# Is there a way to send an alert after I print in iFrame?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, printing

Is there a way to send an alert after I print in iFrame?

This is the code. My code is in an iFrame:

```
function print() { 
    var objFra = document.getElementById('pdf_name'); 
    objFra.contentWindow.focus(); 
    objFra.contentWindow.print(); 
}
```

I tried

```
objFra.contentWindow.addEventListener('afterprint', () => { alert('This document is now being printed })
```

but the alert is not shown.

Comment: send an alert where? You mean just `alert()` on the screen?

Comment: yes, it tried objFra.contentWindow.addEventListener('afterprint', () => {
     alert('This document is now being printed
    })

Comment: but its not returning an alert

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var objFra = document.getElementById('pdf_name'); 
 
objFra.contentWindow.addEventListener('afterprint', () => { 
    alert('This document is now being printed'); 
}); 

objFra.contentWindow.focus();
objFra.contentWindow.print();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bdsg9p3/)

Comment: i have already tried that code but the whole body is poping up in printing not the iframe which is i want